# Unable to log into chat.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, chat, login

I'm currently unable to log into chat.stackexchange.com. The login process seems to stall (I let it go for 10 minutes with no result). Here's a screenshot:

> [image: image of login screen]

I ran the help troubleshooter, and it came back with no issues:

> [image]

I also tried the alternate "log in via Stack Exchange" link, but that seemed to stall out as well.

> [image]

I then deleted my cookies/cache and relogged into my home site (pets.stackexchange.com) and had the same problems (the troubleshooter is still green).

I am using IE8 - I KNOW I KNOW but I don't have a choice for some hours of the day and would like to still be able to keep an eye on activity on my site (since I'm a mod). Is there any help for me?

Edit: I am able to login to chat.meta.stackexchange.com, if is relevant.

Edit: I am able to login on my home computer, so the issue seems restricted to that particular machine and not my account.

Edit: still having issue 5/28/2014

Comment: I have no-repro with a VPC WIN7-IE8. I can login and post messages in chat when using my Google Openid. I do get a javascript error: MozWebSocket not defined.

Comment: have you tried clearing the cookies and whatnot?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yes, I listed that in the question as a step I took.

Comment: IE security settings? If you're stuck on IE8 I'm assuming you're on a company machine and some companies heavily restrict IE. That may block the HTML5/Javascript from working.

Comment: @NathanC all of the tests come back green, though. Is there a specific setting I should look at?

Comment: I hate to +1 this, but having the exact same issue here.