# Unable to log into chat.stackexchange.com, recursive url

Tags: bug, chat, login

I know this is a duplicate of this question: [Unable to log into chat.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230793/unable-to-log-into-chat-stackexchange-com), but I am having the same issue, and have found something else that may be useful.

Whenever I click on the login button, it appends "login%2fglobal%3freturnurl%3dhttp%253a%252f%252fchat.stackexchange.com%252f" to the end of the url, and you can keep clicking on the button and keep getting a longer and longer url (I got up to 2k+ characters in the URL before the page quit!). Every time it still pulls up the same page saying it's logging in but there's no traffic and the page is doing nothing.

I managed to finally log in going through a different route, but I'd still like to post this issue for future reference.

Comment: It would help others if you posted an answer or a comment with how you got in with the different route. I'm having the same problem